# ¿han intentado usar PHPmailer con varias cuentas de correos?

Tags: php, laravel, phpmailer

Tengo el siguiente problema.

```
<?php

namespace App\Strateguies;


use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

use App\Models\Scheduling;

class MailerCommandStrategy
{
    protected  $scheduling, $mail;
    private $emails = [];


    public function start($id)
    {
        $scheduling = Scheduling::find($id);
       
        $this->mail = new PHPMailer(true, 
            [
                'SMTPDebug' => true,
                'SMTPAuth' => true,
                'Mailer' => 'smtp',
                'Host' => $scheduling->credentials->host,
                'Username' => $scheduling->credentials->username,
                'Password' =>  $scheduling->credentials->password,
                'SMTPSecure' => $scheduling->credentials->encryption,
                'Port' => $scheduling->credentials->port,
                'From' => $scheduling->credentials->from_address,
                'FromName' => $scheduling->credentials->from_name,
                'Subject' => $scheduling->html_email->subject,

            ]
        );      
        $this->mail->isHTML(true); 
        $this->list_emails($scheduling);
        $this->sendMailings($scheduling);
    }

    // esta funcion solo saca los correos a los que les enviare correo de la base de datos
    private function list_emails(Scheduling $scheduling)
    {
        foreach ($scheduling->email_list as $email_list) {
            foreach ($email_list->emails as $email) {
                if(!array_search($email->email, $this->emails) && $email->blacklist()->where('scheduling_id', $scheduling->id)->exists()){
                    $this->emails[] = $email;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // aqui hago los envios 
    private function sendMailings(Scheduling $scheduling)
    {
        foreach ($this->emails as $email) {
            try {
                $this->mail->addAddress($email->email, $email->json->firstname.' '.$email->json->lastname);
                

               // compilo la vista con los datos que deben de ir en el correo
                $this->mail->Body =  $this->make_view('mailings.'.$scheduling->html_email->view_path, ['data'=> $email])->render();
                $this->mail->send();
               
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                 print('El mensaje no se envio Mailer error: '. $email->email);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Modifique la librería de PHPmiler para que pudiera setear las configuraciones desde un array de configuraciones. (Se me hace mas limpio que setear las variables en forma de objeto).

Asi quedo el constructor de PHPMiler

```
 public function __construct($exceptions = null, array $options = [])
    {

        if (null !== $exceptions) {
            $this->exceptions = (bool) $exceptions;
        }
        //Pick an appropriate debug output format automatically
        $this->Debugoutput = (strpos(PHP_SAPI, 'cli') !== false ? 'echo' : 'html');

        // set settings
        if(count($options) !== 0){
           foreach ($options as $option => $value) {
               $this->{$option} = $value;
           }
        } 

    }
```

El problema es que estoy seteando las variables en tiempo de ejecución y PHPmiler se queda trabado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me imagino que es porque phpmiler tiene funciones estáticas pero no se me ocurre como reconfigurarlo para que acepte los settings en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Técnicamente todo se hace en tiempo de ejecución, sólo que no estás controlando cuándo se asigna el valor de esas variables y cuándo se crea tu array :)

Comment: No quería hacer una instancia por cada correo al cual le mandare correo. Porque considero que es muy poco elegante el código y muy poco eficiente.

Comment: No estoy diciendo que lo que buscas esté mal. Te estoy diciendo que PHP es todo tiempo de ejecución, no hay compilación o despliegue. Que estás creando tu array después de que se fijan los valores de configuración de PHPMailer y no estás controlando eso

Comment: Hay que tener cuidado porque hasta PHP tiene cache. En el cache es donde se almacenan las funciones **estaticas** por lo que no puedes **setear** variables dinámicamente. En este caso PHPMiler no contemplo que alguien quisiera hacer esto. Y para poder hacer estas configuraciones sin tener que hacer múltiples instancias hay que cambiar la lógica de la clase. Yo quería saber si hay algún artificio como el de la **fachada**  para lograr trabajar con esta clase aun que tenga métodos o funciones estáticos.